# Deadlock on checkout, works after clear log in database

Tags: checkout, deadlock

Hope you guys can help me out, I've a webshop on magento 1.9.0.1 that is giving me problems recently.

When a customer wants to order and he clicks on "Process order" it sometimes take up to 30 seconds before the customer is redirected to the payment provider. Most people then click multiple times on the checkout button off course and that results into a Deadlock error.

I've read that I need to remove the log tables on the databases and yes indeed that works! But now is the question... How can I prevent this kind of error? I don't think it is a solution to clear the log tables in the database 2 times a day..

Hope you guys can help me out!

Comment: what your question i not understand it

Comment: I'm looking for a permanent fix so I don't need to clear de log_ tables twice a day

Comment: Sounds like a MySQL performance issue to me. Are you getting any messages in your system.log when orders are placed?

Comment: Also, what kind of hosting setup is your site using?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors in the system.log, i've got a VPS with 150GB SSD data, 2 core E5-2620, 4GB RAM. I'm not seeing any excessive overuse by any of the runnings applications. Do you know how I can find out if it is a MySQL issue?

Comment: probably you have some extension that breaks in checkout. you need to run `mytop`or enable pdo_debug in Magento

Comment: in fact this could be an issue with your database, could you please post your db size and `mysqltuner.pl` output?

Comment: The DB size is 175MB. You can find the mysqltuner.pl output here: http://pastebin.com/8uWhPg0v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normal Magento store shouldn't see a problem with customer logging enabled - which would indicate that your hosting just isn't good enough.

You could do one of two things,

1. Hide this problem and move on to another problem by disabling [customer logging](https://www.yireo.com/software/magento-extensions/disablelog)
2. Review your hosting infrastructure and size it appropriately

> I've got a VPS with 150GB SSD data, 2 core E5-2620, 4GB RAM

Ditch the VPS/Cloud, move to a proper dedicated service where you aren't sharing or fighting for resources and get at least 8GB RAM (its the bare minimum you should have for a server running Magento).

Once you've got the right size, properly configured hosting - you can turn your focus back to the store. You need to get your foundations right before you build on it.